# How to show youtube videos thumbnails and their title in list view in android

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api

I am Beginner in android and I'm developing an app in which I want to store some youtube videos in arraylist. I want these YouTube videos to be shown in my app as listview of videos which contains thumbnail and title of videos.Whenever the user click on any video from that ListView the video will be played in YouTube app (full screen).
I need both xml and java code for this.
Every kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: You'll learn more if you google for samples and seek help where you are stuck. Start here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

Comment: Basically i am developing toddler app in which toddler poems videos will be shown in list view with their thumbnails and title, so when user clicks any video from listview the video will be played in local youtube app with full screen. and all these videos in my list will played one after another.

Comment: I have searched alot but finds nothing related to this.

Comment: First try to check on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code that you have already done because it will be hard for the community to answer that broad question.